# AWS Step Function JsonMerge new data

Tags: parameters, state-machine, aws-step-functions

The [intrinsic function States.JsonMerge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html#asl-intrsc-func-json-manipulate) works to add a new, static json in the data simulator. So this works in the Parameters in the data simulator to add the newKey to all the incoming input of the state:

```
{
  "input.$": "States.JsonMerge($, { \"newKey\": 1 }, false)"
}
```

[image]

However, in an actual State Machine definition, it rejects that.

[image]

At the least, this seems to show an issue with either the data simulator or the state machine definition rules.

**The question is there a way to do such an operation of adding a new "hard coded" json object like the data simulator allows and format it correctly for the state machine?**

Answer (score 1):

Add a hardcoded key and hardcoded value to the input:

```json
{
  "input.$": "States.JsonMerge($, States.StringToJson('{\"newkey\":1}'), false)"
}
```

Add a hardcoded key and a *substituted* value to the input:

```json
{
  "input.$": "States.JsonMerge($, States.StringToJson(States.Format('\\{\"newkey\":\"{}\"\\}', $.myValue)), false)"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I have a chance to check these out in action, I'll come back and vote/accept...